# joining 2 columns in 1 table

Tags: mysql, join, merge

Im not sure of the right way to do this so help needed if possible please :)

I have a table of football fixtures with the following fields:

id, hteam, ateam, hscore, ascore, date, time

I want to return all the fixtures for one team so where hteam OR ateam = 1 but this doesnt seem to work.

Is there a way I can join or merge these 2 columns to get all the fixture for a particular team?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: please post your code, which isn't working ;)

Comment: do u want that if `ateam = 1` then show `ateam` column otherwise `hteam` column ?

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, you have a single table, and you want to return the row if hteam or ateam is 1?
If so, something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE hteam=1 OR ateam=1`

Answer (score 0):

if u want that if `ateam = 1` then show `ateam` column otherwise `hteam` column  then try

```
SELECT id, hscore, ascore, date, time,
    IF(ateam=1,atem,hteam) AS fixture ,
FROM  fixtures
```